# Link with GNUstep on Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gnustep

I am attempting to compile a simple application that references GNUstep classes, with GNUstep on my Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit, machine:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    NSString *bestType = [[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard]
                          availableTypeFromArray: nil];
    NSLog(@"best type: %@", bestType);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are my compile and link flags (some of which may be overkill):

```
CFLAGS=`gnustep-config --objc-flags` -std=gnu99
LDFLAGS=`gnustep-config --base-libs` -lgnustep-base -lobjc -lm -lglut -lGLU -lGL
```

Before compilation I ran the script:

```
/usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh
```

And here is the output from 'make -n'

```
gcc main.m `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -std=gnu99 -L. `gnustep-config --base-libs` -lgnustep-base -lobjc -lm -lglut -lGLU -lGL -o tester
```

But when linking, Cocoa classes seem to not be pulled in, and I get an undefined reference error:

```
/tmp/ccnyXBoH.o:(.data.rel+0x8): undefined reference to `__objc_class_name_NSPasteboard'
```

If I remove all references to Cocoa classes in main.m, the app compiles without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't find the class definition for `NSPasteboard` is because it's in the `gnustep-config --gui-libs` options - i.e. the symbol is in the gui library of `GNUStep`, not in the base library of `GNUStep`. The solution is to change the `LDFLAGS` line to:

```
LDFLAGS=`gnustep-config --gui-libs` -lglut -lGLU -lGL
```

You shouldn't need to double-specify `-lgnustep-base -lobjc -lm` - they're part of both `--base-libs` and `--gui-libs`.